# viewController not being removed properly?

Tags: ios, swift

In my viewController I have an `NSFetchedResultsController` for populating a `tableView`. In the `viewDidLoad()` I'm saving the current time to a variable, then printing it out in the `NSFetchedResultsController's` `didChange AnyObject` callback:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
    var date: Date!
    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Event>!
   
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        date = Date()
    }

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
        switch type {
        case .insert:
            feedTable.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .fade)
            print(date)
        default:
            break
    }
}
```

I noticed that when I leave this view then come back this callback is called twice and the date from the first time I was in the view is printed as well as the new one:

> 2017-05-14 18:29:42 +0000
>
> 2017-05-14 18:30:01 +0000

I'm leaving the view in a seperate function like this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomePage") as? HomeVC
controller?.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
self.present(controller!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Why does this `MyViewController` seem to stick around even after I leave it and come back? Is the way I'm leaving it not removing it properly?

Comment: Do not forget to call `super` in `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: I am, just didn't include it in this question

Comment: You should update your question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm leaving the view in a seperate function like this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomePage") as? HomeVC
controller?.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
self.present(controller!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Yup, that's the problem. Instead of *returning* to the existing HomeVC, you're making a *new* HomeVC and presenting *that* on top of yourself. So you just keep piling up the view controllers.

What you need to do to get back home is unwind what you did to get here. If `present`, now `dismiss`. If `push`, now `pop`.

Comment: So to get to `MyViewController` I'm using the same kind of storyboard instantiation from the HomeVC. You're saying if I just dismiss then it should take me back home?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "leave the view"
Are you going back? If you are, then deinit is not being called.

Test it by doing the following.

```
deinit {
   print("VC Should deinitialize")
}
```

If this isn't called when you go back, then you have a retain cycle problem.